# Prolog removing IF THEN ELSE

Tags: recursion, prolog, conditional-statements

I would like to reformat my code without the if then else condition. Is there an easy way to do this? This is just an exemple of code. I think using IF-THEN-ELSE in prolog is weird :\ And I'm looking to get something more recursive cases. Like pattern matching

```
rules(Param1, Param2) :-
(
    A ->
        B, C, D,    
        (
            E ->  F
        ;
            G, H
        )    
    ;   
        I
).
```

Edit: Edited my code to look like more what it should look

Comment: Params in Prolog should start with a capital letter if they're uninstantiated variables.

Comment: @mbratch sorry about that, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general translation scheme for

```
pred(X):-
  ( A -> B
  ; C -> D
  ; G
  ).
pred(Y):- Q.
```

is

```
pred(X):- pred1(X).
pred(Y):- Q.

pred1(X):- call(A), !, B.
pred1(X):- call(C), !, D.
pred1(X):- G.
```

Big thanks to [j4n bur53](https://stackoverflow.com/users/502187/j4n-bur53) for pointing out the need for `call` -- [in case there's a cut](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=!/0) inside the `A` or the `C`!

See also [`->` documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=send_arrow/2).

Comment: Hmmm I tried modify my code and it gives me always true after one iteration http://pastebin.com/gkibnMWy

Comment: @Lorac I don't think your mapping quite aligns with Will's rules. I think the parenthetical `( E -> F ; G, H )` would need to be broken out into its own predicate, something like this: http://pastebin.com/gxK0qPEa

Comment: @j4nbur53 ah, right, "meta calling is opaque to the cut" says the docs Thanks for that! But also, if there are more clauses for `pred/1`, needs to be treated more precisely (""Unlike !/0, the choice point of the predicate as a whole (due to multiple clauses) is not destroyed.")...

Answer (score 0):

if-then-else are not really weird. They are part of the ISO core standard, defined in 7.8 Control constructs, 7.8.8 (;)/2 - if-then-else and they have the benefit that various Prolog compilation schemes exist.

[image]

These Prolog compilation strategies are especially useful if the if-then-else appears in the middle of a clause, since the resulting code usually generates less overhead than when the if-then-else would be moved into a separate auxiliary predicate.

The same holds for disjunction (;)/2. As a rule of thumb I would say it is safe, if there is no if-then-else branch that introduces many new variables compared to the other branches. It then makes sense when the Prolog compiler moves variable creation outside of the if-then-else.

Here is an example where if-then-else, in YAP Prolog, shows quite some performance superiour to other programming styles:

```
tarai_cut(X,Y,_,Y) :- X=<Y, !.
tarai_cut(X,Y,Z,R) :-
    X1 is X-1, tarai_cut(X1,Y,Z,Rx),
    Y1 is Y-1, tarai_cut(Y1,Z,X,Ry),
    Z1 is Z-1, tarai_cut(Z1,X,Y,Rz),
    tarai_cut(Rx,Ry,Rz,R).

tarai_or(X,Y,Z,R) :- X=<Y, !, R=Y;
    X1 is X-1, tarai_or(X1,Y,Z,Rx),
    Y1 is Y-1, tarai_or(Y1,Z,X,Ry),
    Z1 is Z-1, tarai_or(Z1,X,Y,Rz),
    tarai_or(Rx,Ry,Rz,R).

tarai_if(X,Y,Z,R) :- X=<Y -> R=Y;
    X1 is X-1, tarai_if(X1,Y,Z,Rx),
    Y1 is Y-1, tarai_if(Y1,Z,X,Ry),
    Z1 is Z-1, tarai_if(Z1,X,Y,Rz),
    tarai_if(Rx,Ry,Rz,R).
```

The if-then-else version runs fastest:

```
   YAP 6.3.3 (i686-mingw32): Sun Jan 20 18:27:56 GMTST 2013

   ?- time(tarai_cut(12,6,0,X)).
   % 0.687 CPU in 0.690 seconds ( 99% CPU)
   X = 12

   ?- time(tarai_or(12,6,0,X)).
   0.734 CPU in 0.735 seconds ( 99% CPU)
   X = 12

   ?- time(tarai_if(12,6,0,X)).
   % 0.515 CPU in 0.516 seconds ( 99% CPU)
   X = 12
```