# Use '->' in prolog

Tags: if-statement, prolog

I want to generate a list that is made up by sublists which contains 2 intergers and their sum and product.

The expected result is

```
A = [[2,3,5,6],[2,4,6,8],[2,5,7,10],[2,6,8,12],
[2,7,9,14],[2,8,10,16],[3,4,7,12],[3,5,8,15],
[3,6,9,18],[3,7,10,21],[4,5,9,20]].
```

But I kept have some sublists that does not have the sum and product:

```
?- get(A).

A = [[2,3,5,6],[2,4,6,8],[2,5,7,10],[2,6,8,12],
[2,7,9,14],[2,8,10,16],[2,_G419,_G422,_G425],
[3,4,7,12],[3,5,8,15],[3,6,9,18],[3,7,10,21],
[3,_G530,_G533,_G536],[4,5,9,20]].
```

Here is my code :

```
get(4,5,[]):-!.
get(N,M,[[N,Q,S,P]|List]):-
    Q is M + 1,
    S is N + Q,
    S =< 10 ->
    P is N * Q,
    get(N,Q,List);
    X is N + 1,
    get(X,X,List).

get(List):-get(2,2,List).
```

I think the problem is about using -> in my code, but I don't know how to fix it, I think the logic about -> is right: `if S=<10, then calculate the product and the other value with N and Q; else calculate N+1 and N+2 and ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operator precedence of (->)/2 is higher than the
operator precedence of (,)/2. As a result the (,)/2
are grouped together as an argument for (->)/2.

So your rule:

```
get(N,M,[[N,Q,S,P]|List]):-
    Q is M + 1,
    S is N + Q,
    S =< 10 ->
    P is N * Q,
    get(N,Q,List);
    X is N + 1,
    get(X,X,List).
```

Is basically read by the interpreter as:

```
get(N,M,[[N,Q,S,P]|List]):-
    (Q is M + 1,
    S is N + Q,
    S =< 10) ->
    P is N * Q,
    get(N,Q,List);
    X is N + 1,
    get(X,X,List).
```

With the result that Q ans S are unbound when
the if condition is not satisfied and the else
part is executed. You can fix your code by introducing
additional parenthesis:

```
get(N,M,[[N,Q,S,P]|List]):-
    Q is M + 1,
    S is N + Q,
    (S =< 10 ->
       P is N * Q,
       get(N,Q,List)
    ;  X is N + 1,
       get(X,X,List)).
```

But even with this fix, there is an issue with P
being unbound in the else branch.

For clarity, you might even try a solution without
if-then-else, see for example here
[Prolog removing IF THEN ELSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469678/prolog-removing-if-then-else)

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Jan, but I want to inteject a point about formatting.  Because ; and -> so strongly affect the meaning of a program, it's poor form (meaning makes it harder to understand) to put those operators at the end of a line.

```
get(N,M,[[N,Q,S,P]|List]):-
      Q is M + 1,
      S is N + Q,
      S =< 10
   -> 
      P is N * Q,
      get(N,Q,List)

   ;  X is N + 1,
      get(X,X,List).
```

When you arrange code like this it becomes immediately apparent that the entire clause is an if-then-else, with the first 3 lines being the 'if' portion.  (Though I wouldn't object to Jan's layout for the final version.)